# why can mongo java driver version 2.4 be used on mongo 2.6?

Tags: java, mongodb, driver

I installed mongodb 2.4 version and used java driver version 2.4.
When I turned to mongodb 2.6 and I forgot to change java driver, but the java driver could also run on mongodb 2.65 version.
I am not sure why.

Comment: your question suggests that there are no problems and your code is still working. If that's the case, this question is best closed. If that was *not* the intention, you need to rephrase something in your question (perhaps you forgot a "not" somewhere?)

Comment: I am a beginner of mongo. The code is working. My current mongodb service is 2.65, and the java driver is for mongodb 2.4.

Comment: And when I use the java driver, which is for mongodb 2.4, it can retrieve data from mongodb 2.6 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They haven't changed how the existing functionality is expressed in the [wire protocol](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/). Instead they just added new features to it. You won't be able to use [new features](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/) with the old driver, but the old stuff should still work ok.

Comment: I bet other drivers even the Javascript shell share the same characters since they are communicated by socket.